# Грамотно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: синтаксис

"Составляя суточный рацион, удобнее начинать с обеда".

Answer (score 1):

Действие, обозначенное деепричастным оборотом, здесь отнесено к тем же подразумеваемым людям, что и действие "начинать". Делая одно,  (вам, ему, диетологу) делать другое (часть упомянутого) удобнее так-то. Поэтому такое предложение возможно, хотя и есть некоторая двусмысленность (сначала пообедать).

Answer (score 0):

Формально я согласен, де-юре фраза грамотна. Но ощущение косноязычности не покидает. Дело не только в том, что фраза двусмысленна (shampar вон вообще до абсурда довел, да еще запятую забыл, - но не видит этой двусмысленности).

Понимаете, чтобы без опаски воспользоваться правилом, о котором говорит Alex_ander, надо чтобы факт одного и того же производителя действия (глагола и деепричастия был понятен раньше чем смысл сказанного.

А у "начинать с обеда" нет какой-то метки, ключевого слова, которое позволяет это сделать.

Я бы не поленился и добавил сюда какое-то слово (любое из не совсем абсурдных) - не для смысла, для гладкости речи.

Составляя суточный рацион, удобнее начинать с **меню** обеда.
Составляя суточный рацион, удобнее начинать с **составления** обеда.
Составляя суточный рацион, удобнее начинать с **рациона** обеда.
Составляя суточный рацион, удобнее начинать с **определения** обеда.

Или любого другого, как сказал, не за смыслом гонимся.

Answer (score -1):

Грамотно. Но лучше так: составлять суточный рацион удобнее начиная с обеда.

Comment: А за завтраком что делать? Ни знаю даже, шутите Вы или нет каждый раз. Если шутите, то неудачно.

Comment: behemothus: Ни знаю даже... Ошибаетесь всякий раз шутя, или стиль оттачиваете?

Comment: Спасибо. Значит, я был прав. Ну что ж, придется заворачивать все ваши подобные т.н. афоризмы.

Comment: behemothus: Формально я согласен, де-юре фраза грамотна.

Comment: Конспективно: 1. behemothus: Формально я согласен, де-юре фраза грамотна. 2. shampar: Грамотно. 3. behemothus: шутите Вы или нет? Я прав.